# How to port libnfc to Android 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich)?

Tags: android, porting, nfc

I came across a [pdf](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEkQFjAE&url=http://wenku.baidu.com/view/8720e0ecf8c75fbfc77db23a.html&ei=AJh8T-DjK8nrrQeVr73TDA&usg=AFQjCNEckeD7q-hbwNBktmNLM2LSz6iwqg&sig2=0MW6dMPHf7DZAfVkDLutCw) online which gave me the porting guide for libnfc to android.

I was wondering if anyone has ported libnfc to Android ICS so that we can use the compiled files directly.

If not, does someone know how to port it apart from the methods suggesed in the pdf?